# Cache some map area of Google Map and then use offline. -swift3

Tags: google-maps, caching, swift3

I am working on an iOS project with Google map and want to save/cache an area/part of the map so that I can use it even if there is no internet. Please help me with this.

Comment: Do I need to give more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found some solution for my own question.

- https://www.imore.com/how-cache-maps-offline-use-google-maps-20-ios
- http://www.cultofmac.com/236643/heres-how-to-cache-your-maps-to-access-google-maps-offline-ios-tips/

May be this will help other.